# MySQL Reg ex, need to match phrases in any order

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using a MySQL Database to search through a list of categories. My query is:

select * from cat where name REGEXP('(region_Long Island)+(.)*(sport_Outdoor Track)');

where the values "region_Long Island" and "sport_Outdoor Track" are passed in. I need to be able to match these categories, regardless of the order they are in. In the table, it is possible to have various combinations of these two categories. I need to match any records that have both of these categories, regardless of what order they are listed in.

I am not able to change the query itself, only modify what is passed into th REGEXP function.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use only a single regexp and you can't change the SQL query, then to match both `A` and `B` in any order, you need a regexp that matches `AB` or `BA`:

```
'region_Long Island.*sport_Outdoor Track|sport_Outdoor Track.*region_Long Island'
```

---

Re your comment:

> What about cases where there are more than two, in any particular order?

If you had patterns `A`, `B`, and `C` any you needed to find all three in any order, you'd need a regexp that matches `ABC`, `ACB`, `CAB`, `CBA`, `BAC`, or `BCA`.  This quickly starts to look like you need *n!* permutations if you have *n* patterns.

That's why a single regular expression is not a good solution for these cases.  You're going to have to use another approach.

> I am not able to change the query itself, only modify what is passed into the REGEXP function.

Sorry, that's not going to work.

Comment: What about cases where there are more than two, in any particular order? For example:

region_Long Island school_someSchool sport_Outdoor Track

If i regex using 'region_Long Island.*sport_Outdoor Track|sport_Outdoor Track.*region_Long Island', then I will exclude any results that aren't listed as sport_Outdoor Track region_Long Island or region_Long Island sport_Outdoor Track, correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    cat
WHERE   name RLIKE 'region_Long Island'
        AND name RLIKE 'sport_Outdoor Track'
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I am not able to change the use of the REGEXP function, i am only able to pass in values.